# How to change AWS API Gateway default responses with SAM template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have an API with AWS API Gateway and Go Lambda functions.

I have an issue, each time when i deploy new version of SAM it Overwrite Gateway responses on API Gateway.

I tried to put it in SAM template but it seems it does not work or I'm not doing it correctly.

Here is SAM template:

```
Resources:
  MyGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: AdminTokenAuthorizer
        AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: False
        Authorizers:
          AdminTokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AdminAuthorizerFunction.Arn
          DeviceTokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt DeviceAuthorizerFunction.Arn
  GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
    Properties:
      ResponseParameters:
        gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
      ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
      RestApiId: !Ref MyGateway
  GatewayResponseDefaultUnauthorized:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
    Properties:
      ResponseParameters:
        gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
      ResponseType: UNAUTHORIZED
      RestApiId: !Ref MyGateway
  GatewayResponseDefault5XX:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
    Properties:
      ResponseParameters:
        gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
      ResponseType: DEFAULT_5XX
      RestApiId: !Ref MyGateway
```

Here is screenshot for Response on AWS console:

[image]

As you can seeheaders are empty for DEFAULT_4XX, UNAUTHORIZED and DEFAULT_5XX.

What i notice is when i rename GatewayResponse resources in template, for example if i rename GatewayResponseDefault4XX to GatewayResponseDefault4XXRename it will set headers correctly for DEFAULT_4XX but if i change something else and deploy it again without changes on GatewayResponses resource it will remove headers from all GatewayResponses.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the parameters. To do this you need to pass it through the parameter [`GatewayResponses`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-gatewayresponses).

Here's a basic example:

```
Resources:
  MyGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      GatewayResponses:
        Default4XX:
          ResponseTemplates: 
            "application/json": {"message": "A super different message"}
        Default5XX:
          StatusCode: 500  # You can set a the status code too
          ResponseTemplates: 
            "application/json": {"message": "And now... something different"}
```